# How to get onclick working on login page, no response when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, button, onclick

When I click login, nothing happens, no activity at all. below Is my current setup.Please help me out and let me know what im doing wrong, any help is much appreciated.

```
<script>
function logIn(){
var username = $("#username").val();
var adpass = $("#adpass").val();

    $.ajax({
 url: 'inc/core_user_functions.php?action=login&username='+username+'&adpass='+adpass,
 success: function(data) {
 // alert(data);
    if(data == 'bad'){
        $("#good").hide();
        $("#bad").fadeIn('slow');
    }else{
        //alert(data);
        $("#bad").hide();
        $("#good").fadeIn('slow');
        setTimeout('update()', 1000); 
    }
  }
});

}


function update(){
//alert('going');
window.location = 'dashboard.php';  
}
$(function(){
$("#username").focus()
$('#adpass').bind('keypress', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode==13){
           logIn();
    }
});
});
</script>

<div class="button" style="width:54px; height:23px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-         serif; font-size:12px; color:#FFF; text-align:center; font-weight:bold; text-shadow: 1px 1px    #2F5132; padding-top:5px; margin-top:15px; margin-left:40px; cursor:pointer" onclick="logIn()">Log      In</div>

</div>
```

Comment: What does alert(data) show you? Also, I'm pretty sure setTimeout first argument should be a function or its name, not a string, try setTimeout(update, 1000)

Comment: Use your browser's Developer Tools to check for errors in the Console and use the javascript debugger. This has nothing to do with php - I updated the tags for you